# Contact form looks fine in codepen, but is messed up in wordpress. Using CF7 and Simple Custom CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am making a contact form for my website, and I put it together in codepen. It looks fine, but when I transfer it over to wordpress, everything is messed up. Specifically my checkboxes. The size of my form is messed up (vertically and horizontally) Some .svg icons are showing, and some aren't? text boxes are longer than they should be, etc. Basically just a bunch of things are messed up, and I have no idea how to fix it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: #ddd;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.contact_info_sec {
  text-align: left; /* Align the text to the left */
  display: flex; /* Use flexbox for positioning */
  align-items: center; /* Center vertically within the container */
  margin-top: 40px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info_single {
  margin-top: 30px; /* Add some spacing between the info sections */
}

.icon-container {
  margin-right: 0px; /* Add spacing between the icon and text */
  display: inline-flex; /* Make sure the icon and text are inline */
  align-items: center; /* Center vertically within each info section */
  
}
.last-icon-container {
  margin-right: 0px; /* Add spacing between the icon and text */
  display: inline-flex; /* Make sure the icon and text are inline */
  align-items: center; /* Center vertically within each info section */
}
.icon-container svg {
  width: 2em; /* Adjust the size of the icons as needed */
  margin-right: 10px; /* Add spacing between the icon and text */
}
.last-icon-container svg {
  width: 2em; /* Adjust the size of the icons as needed */
  margin-right: 10px; /* Add spacing between the icon and text */
}
.icon-container svg:not(:last-child) {
  margin-top: -15px; /* Move all icons up except the last one; adjust the value as needed */
}
.info_single span {
  color: #fff; /* Set text color to white */
  font-size: 16px; /* Adjust font size as needed */
}
/* You can also style the text as needed */
.info_single p {
  color: #9E9E9E; /* Set text color to white */
  font-size: 16px; /* Adjust font size as needed */
  font-weight: 400; /* Adjust font weight as needed */
}
.contact_info_sec h4 {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ddd;
}
.socil_item_inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px; /* Adjust the bottom padding as needed */
}

.socil_item_list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap between icons as needed */
  padding: 0;
}

.socil_item_list li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
input[type='checkbox'] {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.2em 0; /* Smaller spacing */
  align-items: center; /* Align center */
  color: #9e9e9e;
  transition: color 250ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .23, 1);
  width: 200%;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label > ins {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 32px;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: height 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .23, 1);
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label > ins > i {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #e3b316;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label > span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1.1em;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .23, 1);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 1px;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label:hover,
input[type='checkbox']:focus + label {
  color: #fff;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label:hover > span,
input[type='checkbox']:focus + label > span {
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label > ins {
  height: 100%;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label > span {
  border: 0.46em solid #e3b316; /* Slightly smaller border */
  animation: shrink-bounce 200ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .23, 1);
}
@keyframes shrink-bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(0.85) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
.checkbox-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0px; /* Increase spacing between checkboxes */
  margin-top: 22px;
}
.checkbox-group label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Align center */
  font-size: 12pt; /* Increase the font size */
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.contact-form {
  max-width: 1300px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #e3b316;
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
}
.Information-label {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.center-image {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: -100px auto -100px;
  display: block;
}
.form-and-image-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.form-container {
  background-color: #23252b;
  padding: 20px;
}
.image-container {
  background-color: #181b1f;
  padding: 20px;
}
.form-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.text-boxes {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}
html { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 10px; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
li { list-style: none; }
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-top: 0; }
a { text-decoration: none; }
input { border-style: none; background: transparent; outline: none; }
button { padding: 0; background: none; border: none; outline: none; }
.form-group input::placeholder {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
}
.form-group input {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: -0px;
    width: 93%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3b316;
    &:focus {
    border-color: #a88203;
  }
}
.message-group textarea {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 135%;
    z-index: 1;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3b316;
    &:focus {
    border-color: #a88203;
  }    
}
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: left;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px; /*Gradient line length*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1.4rem 2rem 1.6rem;
}

.message-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1.4rem 2rem 1.6rem;
}
textarea {
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  resize: vertical;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.form-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: $input-text-active;
  font-size: 22px;
  vertical-align: left;
}

.submit-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; /* Stack the items vertically */
  margin-top: 200px; /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}
.submit-button {
  background-color: #e3b316;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: auto; /* Move to the bottom */
  align-self: center; /* Center horizontally */
  margin-left: 225px;
}
.submit-button:hover {
animation: pulse 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes pulse {
0% {
transform: scale(1);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #e3b316;
}
70% {
transform: scale(1);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(227, 179, 22, 0);
}
100% {
transform: scale(1.1);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(227, 179, 22, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">
  <div class="form-and-image-container">
    <form action="/your-form-action" method="post" class="form-container">
      <div class="form-content">
        <div class="text-boxes">
          <br>
          <div class="Information-label">Your Information</div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Full_Name" id="full-name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Company_Name" id="company-name" placeholder="Company Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Company_Email" id="company-email" placeholder="Company Email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Company_Email" id="company-email" placeholder="Company Website" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Company_Email" id="company-email" placeholder="Country" required>
          </div>
           <div class="message-group">
            <textarea name="Message" id="message" class="message-textarea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Tell us about your company, and why you require Palmary Lamb." required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="submit-group">
            <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxes-and-label">
          <br>
          <div class="label">Interested Services</div>
          <div class="checkbox-group">
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="interested_services" value="Content Creation" id="one"> 
              <label for="one">
                <span></span>
                Content Creation
                <ins><i>Content Creation</i></ins>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="interested_services" value="Social Media Management" id="two">
              <label for="two">
                <span></span>
                Social Media Management
                <ins><i>Social Media Management</i></ins>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="interested_services" value="Reputation Management" id="three">
              <label for="three">
                <span></span>
                Reputation Management
                <ins><i>Reputation Management</i></ins>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="interested_services" value="Digital Marketing" id="four">
              <label for="four">
                <span></span>
                Digital Marketing
                <ins><i>Digital Marketing</i></ins>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="interested_services" value="Branding" id="five">
              <label for="five">
                <span></span>
                Branding & Identity
                <ins><i>Branding & Identity</i></ins>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="interested_services" value="Event Planning" id="six">
              <label for="six">
                <span></span>
                Event Planning
                <ins><i>Event Planning</i></ins>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="interested_services" value="General Inquiry" id="seven">
              <label for="seven">
                <span></span>
                General Inquiry
                <ins><i>General Inquiry</i></ins>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://palmarylamb.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/IMG_0076.png" class="center-image">
                        <div class="contact_info_sec">
                            <h4>Contact Info</h4>
                            <div class="d-flex info_single align-items-center">
                              <div class="icon-container">
                                <div class="background-shape"></div>
                              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M498.1 5.6c10.1 7 15.4 19.1 13.5 31.2l-64 416c-1.5 9.7-7.4 18.2-16 23s-18.9 5.4-28 1.6L284 427.7l-68.5 74.1c-8.9 9.7-22.9 12.9-35.2 8.1S160 493.2 160 480V396.4c0-4 1.5-7.8 4.2-10.7L331.8 202.8c5.8-6.3 5.6-16-.4-22s-15.7-6.4-22-.7L106 360.8 17.7 316.6C7.1 311.3 .3 300.7 0 288.9s5.9-22.8 16.1-28.7l448-256c10.7-6.1 23.9-5.5 34 1.4z"/></svg>
                                <p><span>marketing@palmarylamb.com</span> - For Marketing Related Questions</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex info_single align-items-center">
                              <div class="icon-container">
                                <div class="background-shape"></div>
                              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M498.1 5.6c10.1 7 15.4 19.1 13.5 31.2l-64 416c-1.5 9.7-7.4 18.2-16 23s-18.9 5.4-28 1.6L284 427.7l-68.5 74.1c-8.9 9.7-22.9 12.9-35.2 8.1S160 493.2 160 480V396.4c0-4 1.5-7.8 4.2-10.7L331.8 202.8c5.8-6.3 5.6-16-.4-22s-15.7-6.4-22-.7L106 360.8 17.7 316.6C7.1 311.3 .3 300.7 0 288.9s5.9-22.8 16.1-28.7l448-256c10.7-6.1 23.9-5.5 34 1.4z"/></svg>
                                <p><span>design@palmarylamb.com</span> - For Design Related Questions</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex info_single align-items-center">
                              <div class="icon-container">
                                <div class="background-shape"></div>
                              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M498.1 5.6c10.1 7 15.4 19.1 13.5 31.2l-64 416c-1.5 9.7-7.4 18.2-16 23s-18.9 5.4-28 1.6L284 427.7l-68.5 74.1c-8.9 9.7-22.9 12.9-35.2 8.1S160 493.2 160 480V396.4c0-4 1.5-7.8 4.2-10.7L331.8 202.8c5.8-6.3 5.6-16-.4-22s-15.7-6.4-22-.7L106 360.8 17.7 316.6C7.1 311.3 .3 300.7 0 288.9s5.9-22.8 16.1-28.7l448-256c10.7-6.1 23.9-5.5 34 1.4z"/></svg>
                                <p><span>support@palmarylamb.com</span> - For Support Related Questions</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex info_single align-items-center">
                              <div class="icon-container">
                                <div class="background-shape"></div>
                              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M498.1 5.6c10.1 7 15.4 19.1 13.5 31.2l-64 416c-1.5 9.7-7.4 18.2-16 23s-18.9 5.4-28 1.6L284 427.7l-68.5 74.1c-8.9 9.7-22.9 12.9-35.2 8.1S160 493.2 160 480V396.4c0-4 1.5-7.8 4.2-10.7L331.8 202.8c5.8-6.3 5.6-16-.4-22s-15.7-6.4-22-.7L106 360.8 17.7 316.6C7.1 311.3 .3 300.7 0 288.9s5.9-22.8 16.1-28.7l448-256c10.7-6.1 23.9-5.5 34 1.4z"/></svg>
                                <p><span>contact@palmarylamb.com</span> - For Everything Else</p>
                            </div>
                          <br>
                            <div class="d-flex info_single align-items-center">
                              <div class="last-icon-container">
                                <div class="background-shape"></div>
                              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><<style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M215.7 499.2C267 435 384 279.4 384 192C384 86 298 0 192 0S0 86 0 192c0 87.4 117 243 168.3 307.2c12.3 15.3 35.1 15.3 47.4 0zM192 128a64 64 0 1 1 0 128 64 64 0 1 1 0-128z"/></svg>
                                <span>Ottawa, ON</span>
                            </div>
                                   <div class="socil_item_inner d-flex">
    <ul class="socil_item_list">
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/palmarylamb/"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M224.1 141c-63.6 0-114.9 51.3-114.9 114.9s51.3 114.9 114.9 114.9S339 319.5 339 255.9 287.7 141 224.1 141zm0 189.6c-41.1 0-74.7-33.5-74.7-74.7s33.5-74.7 74.7-74.7 74.7 33.5 74.7 74.7-33.6 74.7-74.7 74.7zm146.4-194.3c0 14.9-12 26.8-26.8 26.8-14.9 0-26.8-12-26.8-26.8s12-26.8 26.8-26.8 26.8 12 26.8 26.8zm76.1 27.2c-1.7-35.9-9.9-67.7-36.2-93.9-26.2-26.2-58-34.4-93.9-36.2-37-2.1-147.9-2.1-184.9 0-35.8 1.7-67.6 9.9-93.9 36.1s-34.4 58-36.2 93.9c-2.1 37-2.1 147.9 0 184.9 1.7 35.9 9.9 67.7 36.2 93.9s58 34.4 93.9 36.2c37 2.1 147.9 2.1 184.9 0 35.9-1.7 67.7-9.9 93.9-36.2 26.2-26.2 34.4-58 36.2-93.9 2.1-37 2.1-147.8 0-184.8zM398.8 388c-7.8 19.6-22.9 34.7-42.6 42.6-29.5 11.7-99.5 9-132.1 9s-102.7 2.6-132.1-9c-19.6-7.8-34.7-22.9-42.6-42.6-11.7-29.5-9-99.5-9-132.1s-2.6-102.7 9-132.1c7.8-19.6 22.9-34.7 42.6-42.6 29.5-11.7 99.5-9 132.1-9s102.7-2.6 132.1 9c19.6 7.8 34.7 22.9 42.6 42.6 11.7 29.5 9 99.5 9 132.1s2.7 102.7-9 132.1z"/></svg>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/PalmaryLamb"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M389.2 48h70.6L305.6 224.2 487 464H345L233.7 318.6 106.5 464H35.8L200.7 275.5 26.8 48H172.4L272.9 180.9 389.2 48zM364.4 421.8h39.1L151.1 88h-42L364.4 421.8z"/></svg></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

website(bad) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNIbF.png)
Codepen: https://codepen.io/Norbert-Nazari/pen/xxmNJgw?editors=1100

Comment: Use your browser inspector to see what styles are being applied to each element. Did you paste that HTML straight into Contact Form 7, or did you make changes? For example, I don't see any of the CF7 tags in there. If you can edit your question to include the form as you have it in CF7, that might help us.

Comment: @BrettDonald Hi Brett, The HTML was pasted exactly how it looks here into contact form 7. As for the CSS, everything is the same, except every selector has the .wpcf7 selector infront of it. I've tried without it, but I have to put it in since some of my CSS conflicts with the entire site

Comment: Hey Norbert, It is possible that the WordPress default styles are overriding the Contact form CSS. You need to manually edit them so that the specificity is maintained as per WordPress. It is difficult to answer this without looking into the WordPress code.